# python removing a string from another string using lists?

Tags: python, string, list

I need my code to take 2 inputs, a string and a second string. In other words the first string is a sentence of some sort and the second string is just a few letters to be removed from the entire sentence. Example:

```
remove("This is as it is.", "is") == 'Th  as it .'
```

So far I have:

```
def remove(word, reword):
    s = set(reword)
    return (x for x in word if x not in s)

remove("This is as it is.", "is")
print(word)
```

Comment: use `.replace()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the replace function for this.

```
def remove(word, reword):
    return word.replace(reword, '')

word = remove("This is as it is.", "is")
print(word)
```